# Using MkDocs with Github

Tags: c#, mkdocs

How to use mkdocs with github?

I have a repository cloned from the main repository. That case, how do I push the documents (I am using Git on windows).

Comment: Have you tried the `gh-deploy` command as outlined in the [docs](http://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/deploying-your-docs/#github-pages)?

Answer (score 0):

So, I learnt that using gh-deploy is the only way here. I cloned my repo and then used Mkdocs gh-deploy to publish the documentation.